# merging tuples in heap module in python

Tags: python

I wanted to know about the merging behavior of `heap.merge()`.
How does heapq.merge() decide the order when merging a list of tuples.?

I am given two lists each with a 3-tuple,

```
A = [(a, b, c)]
B = [(x, y, z)]
```

where the 3-tuples are of type `(int, int, str)`. I wanted to combine the two lists. I am using `heapq.merge()` operation as it is efficient and optimized for large lists. A and B could contain millions of 3-tuples.

Is it guaranteed that `heap.merge()` will output an order where given two tuples,

```
a >= x and b >= y and c >= z?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python sorts tuples in [lexicographic order](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types):

> first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this
>   determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next
>   two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

---

Take for example,

```
In [33]: import heapq    
In [34]: A = [(1,100,2)]    
In [35]: B = [(2,0,0)]

In [40]: list(heapq.merge(A,B))
Out[40]: [(1, 100, 2), (2, 0, 0)]

In [41]: (1, 100, 2) < (2, 0, 0)
Out[41]: True
```

Thus, it is not necessarily true that

```
a >= x and b >= y and c >= z
```

---

It is possible to use `heapq` on any collection of orderable objects, including instances of a custom class. Using a custom class, you can arrange for any kind of ordering rule you like. For example,

```
class MyTuple(tuple):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return all(a < b for a, b in zip(self, other))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (len(self) == len(other)
                and all(a == b for a, b in zip(self, other)))
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return not (self < other or self == other)            
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self < other or self == other
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return not self < other

A = [MyTuple((1,100,2))]
B = [MyTuple((2,0,0))]
print(list(heapq.merge(A,B)))
# [(2, 0, 0), (1, 100, 2)]
```

Note, however, that although this changes our notion of `<` for `MyTuple`, the result returned by `heapq.merge` is not guaranteed to satisfy

```
a <= x and b <= y and c <= z
```

To do this, we'd have to first remove all items from `A` and `B` which are mutually unorderable.

Comment: Thank you. I came to realize that I misstated my question. I apologize for that. I was meaning to say exactly that. 
Is there anyway we can specify our own comparator?